# VB6 Progress Bar - Resetting Maximum Value

Tags: winforms, user-interface, vb6, progress-bar

I've set up a simple progress bar in a VB6 form using the Microsoft Common Controls 6.0 component, and everything seems to work correctly.

However, I use the progress bar for several different parts of the form, each of which use different (and variable) maximum values.  When I try to change the maximum value at run-time after the bar has already been used once, I get the error `Run-time error '380': Invalid Property Value`.  The progress bar's value is already reset to the minimum before trying to change the max value.

Do these progress bars not allow their max values to be changed after use, or is there some reset method that I'm missing?

```
prgLoading.Min = 1
prgLoading.Max = positions.Count
```

The second line throws the error, and the exact same code is used earlier without any problems.

Comment: Could you please paste the code you use to change the max. value?

Comment: i feel some intermiddiate code is setting the maxvalue to 0(zero). Please share the offending code

Comment: I don't recall any restriction like that with those progress bars. Could you give us a small, working example that shows up the problem for you, with the real values you're using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still reset the **Min** and **Max** properties. Setting **Min** higher than the **Max** or vice-versa will cause a 380 error. You should double check your positions.Count value.

Comment: Ah, nice catch. Turned out positions.Count did go to 0 on a couple occasions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just set `prgloading.value=prgloading.min` before setting `prgloading.max`

Comment: The OP states "The progress bar's value is already reset to the minimum before trying to change the max value." so it's not ths.

Comment: (posting from operamini hence no formating). OP has mentioned that but the  code id not reflecting the same

Comment: No, the exception is saying that the Max value cannot be set, not that the progress bar's value isn't set.